# update table inside for loop

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to update a mysql table while inside a c# for loop and a if statement well a few if statements. While running with a break point it will run the executenonquery once but the next loop it does not hit that. Even when i does hit the nonquery it does not change the table information.

the ffi string is the name of the column in my table and string val is what i want to put in. I know this is not the safe way to do it but I will change it when i can get it working the way it should. 
Updated code it now runs the NONQUERY every time it should but still not updating the table
Code:

```
for (a = 0; a <= z; a++)
 {

   if (ds3.Tables[0].Rows[a][1].ToString() == dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString())
     {
      if (ds3.Tables[0].Rows[a][2].ToString() == dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString())
         {
           if (ds3.Tables[0].Rows[a][3].ToString() == dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString())
            {
              MessageBox.Show("We have a match " +  dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + " " + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() + " " + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[t].Value.ToString());
                     try
                       {
                         string ffi = textBox1.Text;
                          decimal val = decimal.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[t].Value.ToString());


                                                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Update spt_results  SET " + ffi + " = " + val + " where project_Id =" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "",connection2);
                                                //cmd.Connection = connection2;'
                                               // cmd.Connection.Open();

                                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                                //cmd.Connection.Close();
                        }
                      catch
                      {

                      }
```

The message box does show every loop and the connection2.open will run everytime
Thank you for looking and your help
The update string looks like        "update spt_results  SET FFI 300 = '15' where project_Id =AAA007" when it runs

Brent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If uncomment your code: *The connection is open correctly and your code should work. But I'd suggest you to open connection once, before the loop, and close it at the end.*

Another point is that you catched ALL exceptions, it is not good. The problem can be with the query, try to run "update spt_results SET FFI 300 = '15' where project_Id =AAA007" in the console or another MySQL client. It will throw an error. The field name 'FFI 300' must be quoted because it contains a white space and the value 'AAA007' must be quoted as a string literal. Try this query -

```
UPDATE spt_results SET `FFI 300` = '15' WHERE project_Id = 'AAA007'
```

Comment: Thank you moving the open connection and changing the string worked great I had been playing in the sql of MyphpAdmin and found i have to quote the FFI but just could not seem to get it right Thank you again

Answer (score 5):

Look at your code:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = // ... snip SQL injection invitation
connection2.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection2.Close();
```

The `MySqlCommand` has no connection. You're opening and closing *a* connection, but it's got nothing to do with the command. I'd actually expect `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` to throw an exception because it has no connection...

Note that you should use `using` statements for the command and connection, to ensure that all the resources get cleaned up even in the face of an exception.

Comment: `if (string.Equals(answer.Author,"Jon Skeet"))
{
    Damascus.ClickUpArrow();
}`

Answer (score 3):

use  `cmd.Connection = connection2;` just after `connection2.Open();`.

When you trying to execute the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`, it is raising the error for no Connection bounded with the Command and error is caught in catch block. You didn't came to know because you have not doing anything in catch block for the errors.

Comment: I tried to put this in and it still does the same my update string is "update spt_results  SET FFI 300 = '15' where project_Id =AAA007" but even with cmd.Connection = connection2; it only runs the nonquery once